# BigQuery PARSE_TIMESTAMP with unix timestamp - Failed to parse input string

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this

| email | created_date |
| --- | --- |
| me@you.com | 1617753600000 |
| you@me.com | 1601510400000 |

bigquery tells me that `created_date` is stored a string. So I need to transform `created_date` from a unix timestamp into a date.

- First I tried
  `PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%s", created_date)` but got error: `Failed to parse input string "1617753600000"`
- Then I tried `TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(created_date as int64)) as submitted_at` which displays the date correctly `Wed Apr 07 2021`

I'm curious why does `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` not work in this case? Isn't this how it should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` - stands for "The number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC",  but looks like you've got microseconds instead.
Try this: `parse_timestamp("%s", left(created_date, 10))`

Answer (score 2):

You have Unix epoch time represented in milliseconds rather than the more common seconds.  I recommend using the `timestamp_millis()` function:

```
select timestamp_millis(cast(created_date as int64))
```

Note that there are also functions for `timestamp_micros()` and `timestamp_seconds()`.